# Run UITests with different arguments in one session

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, xctest, uitest

I'm trying to run a UITest which requires to change launch arguments in the middle of the run and relaunch the application with new arguments. In theory, `XCUIApplication.launch` should do both terminating and relaunching the application with new arguments however I found it unreliable and not always happening. Then I switched to:

```
func launchAndWaitForLoadingViewFinish() {
    terminate()
    sleep(5)
    launch()
    waitOnLoadingView()
}
```

To terminate manually and then wait on to make sure it is closed and hopefully out of memory before relaunching the app. But still no luck and it fails from time to time. Any recommendation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shall try https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnelHost

This tool allows to synchronously execute macOS console commands while the test is running.

The console commands you need are

```
xcrun simctl terminate ...
xcrun simctl launch ...
```

Comment: But how can you run this when you're in middle of UI test case?

Comment: Just use `host.executeCommand("scrun simctl ...")` wherever you want.

Answer (score -1):

Sleeps are problematic at the best of times. There's a `wait(for:timeout:)` function that might do a better job.